# Can I use a cart software like shopify with my custom website?

Tags: web-development, website-design, ecommerce

I'm sure there is an obvious answer to this question, but can't seem to find it.

I'm building a custom site for a client (html/php) and need to have a web store on it. Building a web store from scratch is too daunting for me in the time I have, so I'm looking at using a prepackaged e-commerce solution like shopify, et al.

My question is whether I can use something like shopify on my site, or whether they (shopify) require you to use their website builder tool. Is it possible to only use the e-commerce tools for stuff like a cart function and checkout page without having to redesign the site or use a site builder/theme? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Shopify is a great eCommerce system that will handle everything for you.

> Is it possible to only use the e-commerce tools for stuff like a cart function and checkout page without having to redesign the site or use a site builder/theme?

You can there are two approaches, one building an end-to-end integration with Shopify or create a sub-domain with Shopify.

- You could, however, it will require building an integration between
  Shopify and your custom website.

  Shopify has great documentation to build integrations like that you can find more about this documentation at
  https://help.shopify.com/api/reference.
- Another alternative is building a basic Shopify store with a default theme and create a sub-domain that points into that store. For instance, your website domain is going to be example.com and your store domain will be something like shop.example.com.

The second solution is the easiest low-maintenance solution. The first solution is a bit more complicated because you need to build the integration.